# Update Oracle DB table from Postgres/PostGIS DB query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, oracle-dbms

I have an Oracle DB where Geolocation (Longitude, Latitude) data is storing. I want to update another column which is the neighborhood of that geolocation. Currently, I do not have oracle spatial support. I have that neighborhood polygon stored in Postgresql DB in PostGIS format. I can easily update that geolocation to the neighborhood in Postgresql through `ST_Contains` function. Is there any way to update Oracle neighborhood column using PostgreSQL DB?

Comment: Choose one RDBMS or the other, but messing around with bridging between them is just asking for trouble. You don’t need Spaial to use the SDO_GEOMETRY datatype.

Comment: Is it possible to use spatial functions(i.e. sde.st_contains  in Oracle) of Oracle without spatial license?

Comment: I actually don't know whether ST_Contains or similar type function is available or not in Oracle without spatial license

Comment: All 2D vector data processing comes with all Oracle database licences under the name “Oracle Locator”. Free of charge. No need for Oracle Spatial Licences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PostgreSQL Foreign Data Wrappers (FDW) to read and write to other databases.  Here is and [overview of FDW](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2016/09/11/a-tour-of-fdws/) that I have found useful.

There seems to be a maintained and fairly [feature complete implementation for Oracle](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw).

What the FDW does is create a local "table" that is really a connection to the foreign table.  You can then use it as you would a local table with SELECTS, INSERTS, etc.

I've used FDWs extensively and think they're great.  They make working with multiple databases a breeze.  That said, I haven't used one with Oracle before.

Comment: Here is a discussion with a relevant example https://community.oracle.com/message/14913928#14913928

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Vince:

> Choose one RDBMS or the other, but messing around with bridging
>   between them is just asking for trouble. You don’t need Spatial to use
>   the SDO_GEOMETRY datatype.

and as clarified by @AlbertGodfriend:

> All 2D vector data processing comes with all Oracle database licences
>   under the name “Oracle Locator”. Free of charge. No need for Oracle
>   Spatial Licences.